# Relation between number of repeated rows with algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

While analysing a particular type of graph, I got an adjacency matrix $A$ in the general block form $A=\begin{pmatrix}\begin{array} \\B&C\\C^T&D\end{array}\end{pmatrix},$ where $B$ and $D$ are square matrices (need not be of same order) and $C$ is an $m \times n$ matrix. The matrix $A$ has a certain number of repeated rows and vanishing trace. Can we relate the number of repeated rows with the multiplicity of the eigen value $0$?

OR any type of estimate is possible for the multiplicity?

Comment: Because $A$ is symmetric, the algebraic and geometric multiplicities of $A$ will be the same. The number of repeated rows gives a lower bound for this multiplicity.

Comment: Are either of the matrices $B$ and $D$ invertible?

Comment: Sir, How can we justify the lower bound ?

Comment: $B$ and $D$ need not be invertible, what we can conclude if they were?

Comment: Sir, we need $B$ and $D$ symmetric to say $A$ is symmetric, right?

Comment: Actually, $B$ is non-singular but $D$ is singular.

Comment: Because $A$ has repeated columns (equivalently repeated rows), we know that there are corresponding non-zero solutions to $Ax = 0$. Those solutions are eigenvectors of $A$ associated with the eigenvalue $0$. Notably, the eigenspace of $A$ associated with $\lambda = 0$ is simply the nullspace of  $A$.

Comment: If $B$ is non-singular, then we can make use of the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) to say that the (algebraic) multiplicity of $\lambda = 0$ for the matrix $A$ is equal to the multiplicity of $\lambda = 0$ for the matrix $A/B = D - C^\top B^{-1} C$.